# Android Wakelock working only if USB connected (4.2.2 only)

Tags: android, wakelock

I'm using wake lock to turn on screen.

```
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
//acquiring wake lock
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (mWakeLock == null) {
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), TAG);
        }
        if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
            mWakeLock.acquire();
        }
//releasing wakelock
Runnable releaseWakelock = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("timeout","timeout!!!");
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
                if (mWakeLock != null && mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                    mWakeLock.release();
                }
            }
        };
        new Handler().postDelayed(releaseWakelock, WAKELOCK_TIMEOUT);
```

I also added permission to AndroidManifest

When tested, it works normally in my galaxy note2 4.4.2, so I guess my code is at least partially right

However, my galaxy s4 lte-a (4.2.2) works normally when usb connected, but it doesn't when it is not connected via usb cable.

What is the problem?? I found some questions posted by people with similar problems, but none had satisfying answer.

Is it 4.2.2 known bug?? or am I doing something wrong??

Please help if you have any idea

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's  not a bug.  The code is ok

Comment: Then why isn't it working properly?? My app is a alarm and when alarm time comes, I start activity and I'm acquiring wake lock in onCreate(). Can it be a problem? (Maybe my device is sleeping so it cannot start activity or run onCreate()??)

Comment: first of all what is "not working" ? second, where do you acquire the wake lock?

Comment: Oh, not working means the device screen does not turn on. I used wakelock hoping that it will turn on device screen.
I acquire wake lock as follows. At specific time my alarmManager wakes up the device with AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, it starts service with pendingIntent and the service starts activity and wake lock is acquired in the activity's onCreate(). I believe that RTC_WAKEUP wakes my device, so it seems possible to acquire wake lock in onCreate() but why won't it work??

Comment: shouldn't AlarmManager start a BroadcastReceiver instead of Service?

Comment: alarmManager has service as its 'operation' like follows. intent = new Intent(mContext, NotiService.class);PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent); So I believe that it starts the NotiService.

Comment: i mean: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html, read the second paragraph starting with: "The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm receiver's onReceive() method is executing"

Comment: Oh I got it!! Starting service was not a problem(I don't know for sure but i guess onStartCommand() works as onReceive()). The problem was that I execute asyncTask in service and return onStartCommand(). As you said, the onReceive(in my case the onStartCommand) was no longer executing so that was the problem.. Thanks you are a lifesaver!!